# java persistence error CRUD

Tags: java, mysql, entity-framework, netbeans, persistence

i currently have a mysql database and i have created entity classes in netbeans. it has generated the relevant classes. i am now trying to create CRUD (create, retrieve, update, delete) clases for each entity. however whenever i try to test it i get a big persistence error. Please see error below.

---

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@36029483
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [educationhub2PU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7220] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field studentStudentID] from the entity class [class entitiyclasses.Test] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at crud.inspirationCrud.create(inspirationCrud.java:24)
    at crud.tester.main(tester.java:20)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [educationhub2PU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7220] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field studentStudentID] from the entity class [class entitiyclasses.Test] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1954)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1945)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:96)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [educationhub2PU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7220] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field studentStudentID] from the entity class [class entitiyclasses.Test] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:230)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7220] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field studentStudentID] from the entity class [class entitiyclasses.Test] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.incompleteJoinColumnsSpecified(ValidationException.java:1847)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.getJoinColumnsAndValidate(MappingAccessor.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.getJoinColumns(MappingAccessor.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ObjectAccessor.processForeignKeyRelationship(ObjectAccessor.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ObjectAccessor.processOwningMappingKeys(ObjectAccessor.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ManyToOneAccessor.process(ManyToOneAccessor.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processOwningRelationshipAccessors(MetadataProject.java:1580)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage3(MetadataProject.java:1833)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1869)
    ... 7 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

---

method used to test the inspirationCrud class method create

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //studentCRUD crud = new studentCRUD();
         //crud.create("feedback","A", 10, 10, 2);

         inspirationCrud cru = new inspirationCrud();
         cru.create(23,"happy","05/01/2015");
    }
```

---

the entity class is inspiration and the class which is doing the CRUD is called inspirationCrud

**InspirationCrud class**

```
public void create(int id,String qou, String dat){
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("educationhub2PU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Inspiration b = new Inspiration();
        b.setQouteID(id);
        b.setQoute(qou);

        String expectedPattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(expectedPattern);
            try {
                b.setDateTime(formatter.parse(dat));
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(inspirationCrud.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        em.persist(b);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

**inspiration entity class generate by netbeans**

```
package entitiyclasses;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author Waleed
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "inspiration")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Inspiration.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM Inspiration i"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Inspiration.findByQouteID", query = "SELECT i FROM Inspiration i WHERE i.qouteID = :qouteID"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Inspiration.findByQoute", query = "SELECT i FROM Inspiration i WHERE i.qoute = :qoute"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Inspiration.findByDateTime", query = "SELECT i FROM Inspiration i WHERE i.dateTime = :dateTime")})
public class Inspiration implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Qoute ID")
    private Integer qouteID;
    @Column(name = "Qoute")
    private String qoute;
    @Column(name = "Date & Time")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateTime;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "inspirationQouteID")
    private List<Student> studentList;

    public Inspiration() {
    }

    public Inspiration(Integer qouteID) {
        this.qouteID = qouteID;
    }

    public Integer getQouteID() {
        return qouteID;
    }

    public void setQouteID(Integer qouteID) {
        this.qouteID = qouteID;
    }

    public String getQoute() {
        return qoute;
    }

    public void setQoute(String qoute) {
        this.qoute = qoute;
    }

    public Date getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(Date dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Student> getStudentList() {
        return studentList;
    }

    public void setStudentList(List<Student> studentList) {
        this.studentList = studentList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (qouteID != null ? qouteID.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Inspiration)) {
            return false;
        }
        Inspiration other = (Inspiration) object;
        if ((this.qouteID == null && other.qouteID != null) || (this.qouteID != null && !this.qouteID.equals(other.qouteID))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entitiyclasses.Inspiration[ qouteID=" + qouteID + " ]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Show `class entitiyclasses.Test`. There is the Problem. And Show class Student

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you answer